# How to renew expired manage package in salesforce

Tags: appexchange, licenses

I am a partner user with a managed package live on app exchange.
A customer has installed the package in enterprise production org from appexchange but it expired after trial period.

In the listing I have selected "**Paid without Checkout Option**".

I have to renew their license without reinstalling and loosing data. How should I renew this expired package?

Comment: Using your lma in your business org

Answer (score 4):

In LMA for license object add "Modify License" button on page layout.

Using this button license details such as status, expiration date can be modified.